# How to display the total discount amount on my shopping cart?

Tags: magento-1.8, totals, grand-total, discount

How can I display the total discount amount on my shopping cart?

I can get the subtotal and grandtotal from the code below, but what about the total discount?

```
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
$grandTotal = $quote->getGrandTotal();
$subTotal =  $quote->getSubtotal();
var_dump($subTotal);
```

What I need,

```
Subtotal           €220
Discount           €20
TOTAL AMOUNT       €200
```

What from Magento,

```
Subtotal           €200 // should be €220
Discount           
TOTAL AMOUNT       €200
```

I'm using Magento 1.8

Comment: can you please share the steps how do you add this in your folder in details of each point it will very help full to magento beginor and others also. +1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you had a common problem, some time we not get discount amount by default in magento, please go to this link i hope you will definitely got solution

http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/269154/

you may also check this type of problem

http://magento.ikantam.com/qa/how-add-discount-total-magento

Comment: is it correct Answer you find here , i think it will help you lot.

Comment: Yes it is. I got it confused with the discount and special price.

Comment: @AmitKamboj can you pleae tell which config.xml file need to edit to achive this and also share some details.i am very stucked on this issue hope

Comment: @AmitKamboj   can you please share the steps how do you add this in your folder in details of each point it will very help full to magento beginor and others also. +1

Comment: This is a link only answer. Furthermore, the because of linkrot, the link you posted to does no longer exist. Please be aware that when answering, give the solution in your answer as well as linking.